# The quadratic equation errors

Tags: java

Not completely sure how to use this site, so if the question is too vague I apologize.

I'm supposed to use the quadratic equation to find roots, but whenever I input the variables for a, b, and c it returns a wrong answer. I'd like to know what the problem in my code is.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Quadratic
{
 private int a, b, c;
 private double rootOne;
 private double rootTwo;

 public Quadratic()
 {
   setEquation(0,0,0);
   rootOne=0;
   rootTwo=0;
 }

 public Quadratic(int quadA, int quadB, int quadC)
 {
   setEquation(quadA, quadB, quadC);
   rootOne=0;
   rootTwo=0;
 }

 public void setEquation(int quadA, int quadB, int quadC)
 {
   a = quadA;
   b = quadB;
   c = quadC;
  }

 public void calcRoots( )
 {
   rootOne = (-b + (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b,2)) - ((4 * a * c))))/(2*a));
   rootTwo = (-b - (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b,2)) - ((4 * a * c))))/(2*a));
 }

 public void print( )
 {
   System.out.println("rootone :: " +rootOne);
   System.out.println("roottwo :: " +rootTwo);
 }
}
```

Comment: any reason why a,b,c are integers ?

Comment: You mixed parenthesis. Your formula is `-b ± (sqrt(delta)/2a)` instead of `(-b ± sqrt(delta))/2a`. Make your code easier by splitting your calculations. First calculate `double delta = Math.pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c;` then use it in rest of your calculations `rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a);` `rootTwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets in the wrong place:

```
(-b + (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b,2)) - ((4 * a * c))))/(2*a))
```

Removing extraneous brackets, your code is doing:

```
-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c) / (2 * a)
```

So `-b` is not being divided by `2a`, you probably want:

```
(-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
```

Also, as Manos mentioned, `int` is not a great choice for the type.

Here's something where approaching by pieces would benefit understanding and maybe performance:

```
double t1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);
double t2 = 2 * a;
rootOne = (-b + t1) / t2;
rootTwo = (-b - t1) / t2;
```

It's a common style in programming to avoid having the code do the same operations multiple times, especially things like powers and square roots.

Comment: Nice answer. I would like to add that in these cases it is worth to use a class for complex values, since there is a possibility that (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c) < 0, where there are no real solutions, but there are complex solutions.

Comment: This is some high quality answer! Yimin is Rong but not wrong, he is so right in this answer! Props. 
OP, I hope your problem is fixed.

Comment: Why use Math.pow(b,2) when b*b will do?

Comment: Because a code with b * b is not as clear, especially for beginners.